# PHP - Replace data within multidimensional array, specific key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm relearning PHP, so sorry for might be a basic question. I can't find an answer.

I have a multidimensional array, I need to replace the value for a specific key (all instances of) with another value.

```
Array ( 
    [13] => Array ( 
                [ad_id] => 13 
                [ad_name] => Qhxxst 
                [ad_link] => www.qxxst.co.uk 
                [ad_type] => 1 
            ) 
    [15] => Array ( 
                [ad_id] => 15 
                [ad_name] => Pxxly 
                [ad_link] => http://pixxly.net 
                [ad_type] => 1 
            ) 
    [16] => Array ( 
                [ad_id] => 16 
                [ad_name] => cxxm 
                [ad_link] => http://www.cxxm.co.uk 
                [ad_type] => 1 
            ) 
)
```

I wish to replace all instances of ad_type with another value. 
i.e. 
Where ad_type = 1, replace with x
Where ad_type = 2, replace with y

I've been using `str_replace` and `json_decode` without success. They either replace all instances of '1' or nothing at all. I need to target ad_type keys only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best way to access the keys and values of an array is  with foreach loop.

Something like:

```
$array= Array ( [13] => Array ( [ad_id] => 13 [ad_name] => Qhxxst [ad_link] => www.qxxst.co.uk [ad_type] => 1 ) [15] => Array ( [ad_id] => 15 [ad_name] => Pxxly [ad_link] => http://pixxly.net [ad_type] => 1 ) [16] => Array ( [ad_id] => 16 [ad_name] => cxxm [ad_link] => http://www.cxxm.co.uk [ad_type] => 1 ) );

foreach ($array as $key=>$val) 
{
    if ($key=="ad_type" && $val==1) 
    {
        $val="x";
    }
    elseif ($key=="ad_type" && $val==2) 
    {
        $val="y";
    }
}
```

For further reference http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: This answer clearly does not work. It you are to pursue this path you need a double loop. Take a look at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a24a4a92664467864f81ecc76e81b4079a7c261

Comment: This method does not work in any multi dimension array. """foreach ($arrayName as &$value) {
    $value['ValueName'] = str_replace($value['ValueName'],encryptText($value['ValueName']),$value['ValueName']);
}""" worked for me

Answer (score 14):

```
foreach($array as &$value) {
    $value['ad_type'] = 'new value';
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Using your example got it sorted. 'code' foreach($qresult as &$value) {
    $value['ad_type'] = str_replace ("1","Interstatial",$value['ad_type']);
    $value['ad_type'] = str_replace ("2","Top Frame",$value['ad_type']);

}